# How to condense a single dataframe based on the index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
                    label scoreCTBIN004v1  scoreCTBIN003v1  scoreCTBIN001v1  
    Overall Stress Score              54              NaN              NaN     
            Stress Score              50              NaN              NaN     
  Short-Term Stress Risk              50              NaN              NaN
      Future Stress Risk              59              NaN              NaN
     Chronic Stress Risk              55              NaN              NaN
    Overall Stress Score             NaN             57.0              NaN
            Stress Score             NaN             52.0              NaN
  Short-Term Stress Risk             NaN             52.0              NaN
      Future Stress Risk             NaN             65.0              NaN
     Chronic Stress Risk             NaN             59.0              NaN
    Overall Stress Score             NaN              NaN             57.0
            Stress Score             NaN              NaN             49.0
  Short-Term Stress Risk             NaN              NaN             54.0 
      Future Stress Risk             NaN              NaN             66.0 
     Chronic Stress Risk             NaN              NaN             60.0
```

I simply want to condense the label column so that they are all on the same row, but it is not combining the labels even though they are the same name?

Something simple like this:

```
                    label scoreCTBIN004v1  scoreCTBIN003v1  scoreCTBIN001v1  
    Overall Stress Score              54              57              57     
            Stress Score              50              52              49     
  Short-Term Stress Risk              50              52              54
      Future Stress Risk              59              65              66
     Chronic Stress Risk              55              59              60
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.pivot_table` in this case.

```
data = {'label':['Overall Stress Score','Stress Score','Short-Term Stress Risk','Future Stress Risk','Chronic Stress Risk']*3,'scoreCTBIN004v1':[1,2,3,4,5]+[np.nan]*10,'scoreCTBIN003v1':[np.nan]*5+[6,7,8,9,10]+[np.nan]*5,'scoreCTBIN001v1':[np.nan]*10+[1,2,3,4,5]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

pd.pivot_table(df,index='label')
Out[21]: 
                        scoreCTBIN001v1  scoreCTBIN003v1  scoreCTBIN004v1
label                                                                    
Chronic Stress Risk                 5.0             10.0              5.0
Future Stress Risk                  4.0              9.0              4.0
Overall Stress Score                1.0              6.0              1.0
Short-Term Stress Risk              3.0              8.0              3.0
Stress Score                        2.0              7.0              2.0
```

Comment: As you can see, the 'label' column becomes indexes. I'm not sure if you are  ok with this.

Comment: Is there a way to not hard code the column value names? They will be constantly changing so that won't be possible for me. Also, the label column is already indexes which i think may be part of the problem

Comment: Actually, you can ignore the values parameter and you will get the same thing. See the updated code. However, you can always do `df.columns[1:]` for the values parameter

Answer (score 1):

If that is an accurate representation of your whole dataset, you could `groupby` your 'label' column, and keep `'first'` values:

```
df.groupby('label',as_index=False).first()
```

prints:

```
                   label  scoreCTBIN004v1  scoreCTBIN003v1  scoreCTBIN001v1
0     Chronic Stress Risk             55.0             59.0             60.0
1      Future Stress Risk             59.0             65.0             66.0
2    Overall Stress Score             54.0             57.0             57.0
3  Short-Term Stress Risk             50.0             52.0             54.0
4            Stress Score             50.0             52.0             49.0
```

Comment: I truly thought this would work as well, but my dataframe is still producing the same result as above.  The dataframe I gave is the result of appending other dataframes onto it, but for all intents and purposes that is the end result DF that I'd like to make the change to.

Answer (score 0):

clean and simple if you really have this format:

###### if label is the index:

```
df.stack().unstack()
```

output:

```
                        scoreCTBIN004v1  scoreCTBIN003v1  scoreCTBIN001v1
label                                                                    
Chronic Stress Risk                55.0             59.0             60.0
Future Stress Risk                 59.0             65.0             66.0
Overall Stress Score               54.0             57.0             57.0
Short-Term Stress Risk             50.0             52.0             54.0
Stress Score                       50.0             52.0             49.0
```

###### if it is a column:

```
df.set_index('label').stack().unstack().reset_index()
```

output:

```
                    label  scoreCTBIN004v1  scoreCTBIN003v1  scoreCTBIN001v1
0     Chronic Stress Risk             55.0             59.0             60.0
1      Future Stress Risk             59.0             65.0             66.0
2    Overall Stress Score             54.0             57.0             57.0
3  Short-Term Stress Risk             50.0             52.0             54.0
4            Stress Score             50.0             52.0             49.0
```